# How to get workbench/view in Eclipse (e4)?

Tags: eclipse, view, e4, workbench

I'm developing an Eclipse plugin in which I need to access a view.

I've found this way to get the workbench, but I guess it only worked in Eclipse 3.x and I am using Eclipse 4 so it doesn't work:

```
IWorkbench workbench = PlatformUI.getWorkbench();
IViewPart part = workbench.getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage()
            .findView("id_of_the_view");
```

I then found this way:

```
@Inject
private static EPartService epartService;

MPart mPart = epartService.findPart("id_of_the_view");
    MyViewClass part = (MyViewClass)mPart.getObject();
```

which throws a NullPointerException. I've made sure the view is open.

What am I missing?

Edit:

I've also tried this, as found [here (german)](https://jaxenter.de/migration-auf-eclipse-4-einmal-angefangen-gibt-es-kein-zuruck-2132)

```
 @Inject
 private static EPartService epartService;
 @Inject
 private static MApplication application;   
 @Inject
 private static EModelService modelService;
 ...
MUIElement element = modelService.find("id_of_the_view", application);
    if(element instanceof MPart) {
        MPart part = (MPart) element;
...
}
```

but I also get a NPE in the .find()-line.

Comment: Using `EPartService` is correct. What is null - the mPart or epartService? Are you sure the id is correct?

Comment: Don't use `static` for injected objects. Where are you running this code?

Comment: Sorry, the Exception is thrown in this line: MPart mPart = epartService.findPart("id_of_the_view"); (i.e. mPart doesn't become null, but a NullPointerException is thrown).

Yes, sadly I am sure that the id is correct. I copy-pasted it from the plugin.xml of the plugin which created it.

Edit: I am running it from a test-class, which contains the main of my project and a method to access the view. I guess I will have to split it to make it non-static.

Comment: Only classes which are created by Eclipse from objects described in the Application.e4xmi are injected. If you are creating a class using `new` it is not injected.

Comment: I do not have the file Application.e4xmi. I've created my project from existing source I've started writing outside an Eclipse plugin project (I've created a new plugin project and selected the directory of the sources as the location). I guess this was wrong because I need this file which was not created?

Comment: Looks like you are still using the 3.x compatibility mode so you should not be trying to use injection. In that case PlatformUI is the correct thing to use - but that must run as part of an Eclipse plugin in a properly initialized Eclipse.

Comment: Hey, thank you. Regarding your last part: The plugin which I want to extend opens a new Eclipse window when I run it. There I have the functions the plugins offers. And that's where I develop and (try to) run my code. Seems like this is wrong and that's why I get the error message that the Workbench is not created when I try to run the first example code? It should then work if I add my code as a call in the initial plugin so it's compiled / run at the same time?

Comment: Your code must be in Eclipse plugin.

Answer (score 2):

You're right. In E4 you should use injection.

To avoid NPEs, you can get the reference to the IEclipseContext in part constructor.

```
public class MyPart {
    private IEclipseContext context;

    @Inject
    public MyPart(IEclipseContext context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

}
```

Assuming you have your part class defined in a plugin, and that the class is referenced as Part in an E4 Application, you can get a reference to the Part instance using its id

[image: Part is defined in E4 Application model]

Somewhere in your code you use the id to get an instance of your part

```
// somewhere in your code ..
// (where you can access the context instance)
MPart myPart = getPart(context, "com.example.myPart");
```

The easy way is to use EPartService.findPart() , as follows:

```
/** with this method I can get reference to the part */
public static MPart getPart(IEclipseContext context, String partId) {
    EPartService partService = context.get(EPartService.class);
    MPart part = partService.findPart(partId);
    return part;
}
```

**Beware of static methods**. Context Objects and static members are not friends !!

For multiple matches, or advanced searches, you can use EPartService.findElements(), as follows :

```
    public static List<MPart> getParts(IEclipseContext context,
        MWindow workbenchWindow, String partId) {

        EPartService partService = context.get(EPartService.class);
        EModelService modelService = context.get(EModelService.class);
        List<MPart> parts =
                modelService.findElements(workbenchWindow, partId, MPart.class,
                        null, EModelService.OUTSIDE_PERSPECTIVE
                                | EModelService.IN_ANY_PERSPECTIVE
                                | EModelService.IN_SHARED_AREA);
        return parts;
    }
```

Comment: Hey, thank you for your input. It sounds interesting and I'll definitly go over it. But as seen in the comments, I was/am using 3.x and not E4 so the problem was easily fixed without all of that stuff.